# Use a custom page with dynamic content as a user profile page

Tags: customization, custom-field, pages, profiles

I'm trying to create a website with fully customised user profile pages. I've created the page which uses dynamic content to pull user custom fields into it, this works fine to view your own profile however I want users to be able to view others profiles. Currently when you try to view another users profile obviously it just pulls in the logged in users info, not the profile you're trying to view.

I realise this problem is overcome by using a profile builder plugin however i've tried many of these and they don't allow you to fully customise the profile page as I need.

Is there a way to have a fully customised user profile page that can be viewed by others? Would using custom post types work for this?

Comment: How do you get your user data? `wp_get_current_user()` gets data for the current user only. With `get_user_by('id', $user_id)` or `get_userdata($user_id)` you can get user data based on another user ID.

Comment: I have been using ACF and Elementor Pro with dynamic tags to get the User Meta data. Where would I implement get_user_by or get_user_data for this?

Comment: I dont work with these plugins, but the posted functions are default WordPress functions. Which for example can be used in a custom plugin, your theme functions.php or inside template files. I dont think you can use them directly inside Elementor or ACF. Maybe you should ask the developers of these plugins. Explaing all this will be too much here I think if you dont know what you are doing.

Comment: LWS-Mo is correct and you'd probably be able to get a bit more feedback if you actually included some code that we could all look over.  I know how I'd do this but I have no idea what you've built thus far or how, so I can't even begin to offer an suggestions.

Comment: Thank you both for your comments, it seems I am out of my depth here and have enquired for professional help.